# JavaEE 6 support in WSO2 AS 5.1.0

Tags: java-ee-6, wso2

Is WSO2 AS 5.1.0 JavaEE 6 compliant? Can I use in applications to be deployed on the appserver such technologies as Contexts, Dependency Injection, JPA2 and JSF2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSO2 AS 5.1.0 is not a JavaEE compliant server but we are actively considering to be a JavaEE Web Profile compliant server with our future releases. In fact instead of supporting to complete JavaEE WP spec once, our approach is consider one or few specifications at a time and support complete user stories around the specific technologies without just supporting to specification only. Usually we make sure particular technology can be used within WSO2 AS so that the the applications build using this technology can leverage WSO2 platform level benefits into the applications. Further other WSO2 developer  tools such as Developer Studio also improved to support new technology around use cases. As an example instead of supporting to JNDI considering just another Java EE spec, AS 5.1.0 enable users to bind and look-up Carbon data sources as JNDI resources.

Answering to your specific question I'm not sure about time line for CDI but JPA 2.0 and JSF 2.0 supports most likely to be on next WSO2 AS major release. Having said above if you can package all your Java EE dependencies within your application you  can deploy them on WSO2 AS 5.1.0 without any issue just like you deploy them on Tomcat.

FYI WSO2 AS 5.1.0 support for following  specifications.

Servlet 3.0

JSP 2.2

EL 2.2

JSTL 1.2

JNDI

JAX-RS 2.0

JAX-WS 2.2

JAXB 2.2

JMS

SAAJ

JavaMail

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this document [1] to get the information regarding the supported features...

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Features

Regards,

Mohan